# Node.js - Array undefined but logging on console

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, csv

What I'm trying to do is to download a csv file, read it line by line and to add the splitted line (on ',') to `tmparray`.
This code works and prints all the element in the array.

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
readline = require('readline');
try {
    request('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.csv').pipe(fs.createWriteStream("MyCsv.txt"));
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
var inputFile = 'MyCsv.csv';
var tmparray;
//read the file
var rd = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('/home/nome/Node/MyCsv.csv')
});
try {
    //read line by line 
    rd.on('line', (line) => {
        tmparray += line.split(",");

        //print the elements
        tmparray.forEach((element) => {
            console.log(element);
        }, this);
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

What I want to do is to print the array after I assigned it.
I've tried this:

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
readline = require('readline');
try {
    request('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.csv').pipe(fs.createWriteStream("MyCsv.txt"));
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
var inputFile = 'MyCsv.csv';
var tmparray;
//read the file
var rd = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('/home/nome/Node/MyCsv.csv')
});
try {
    //read line by line 
    rd.on('line', (line) => {
        tmparray += line.split(",");


    });
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
} finally {
    console.log(tmparray); // undefined
    // or this: console.log(tmparray[0]) can't read the property '0' of undefined

}
```

but the array is printed as if it is `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `rd.on(...)` is asynchronous.

That means that you are telling `rd` that when it reads a line, it should add it to `tmparray` — but that doesn't actually happen yet. It happens moments later, *after* you `console.log(tmparray)`.

You should say `rd.on('close', () => console.log(tmparray))` to tell Node "when you have finished reading `rd`, *then* log the data".

There are a couple of other issues in the code but they should be easier to find once this is fixed. Looking at it, I think `line` isn't an event on readable streams so you should say `rd.on('data', ...)` instead; and you're trying to build up an array using the `+` operator which doesn't work. It will probably convert everything to strings though, so it should log something fairly reasonable for now.

Comment: Will try tomorrow. Makes sense

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the [csv package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv) it will give you the same result, Here is an example of transforming csv file into array:

```
const csv = require('csv')
    , request = require('request');

var url = 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.csv';

request(url, function (err, response, data) {

    if (err) throw err;

    csv.parse(data, function (err, data) {

        if (err) throw err;

        // here you get your array
        console.log(data);

    });

});
```